# Any way to un-subdivide bare edges (or not subdivide in the frst place)?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, cloth-simulation, subdivision-surface

So, I'm fiddling with cloth sim. Which means, of course, I need lots of faces. I'd prefer to get them via the subdivision modifier so as to not degrade my ability to tweak the original mesh.

I also need to use sewing. Unfortunately, subdividing the bare edges used for sewing makes sewing behave poorly. (Basically, because they have been subdivided, the sewing edges are not pulled as tightly as they should be.)

Is there any way to either subdivide *faces¹ only*, or to collapse *only the bare edges* after the fact? (Even better, is there any way to add new edges between midpoint vertices that were connected by bare edges at both endpoints?)

Here's an illustration:
[image]

Faces are shown in beige. Note that there are only two faces, which are connected by a pair of bare (not associated with any face) edges. I'm trying to get rid of the vertices circled in red, either by not creating them in the first place, or by dissolving all vertices with exactly two connected edges. *Ideally*, subdivision would also create the edge circled in green².

---

¹ Pedantically, it would be more accurate to say "only edges which belong to one or more faces", which is to say that *bare* edges should not be subdivided.

² For every closed edge loop `ABCD` where `AB`, `CD` are bare edges and `AD`, `BC` are non-bare edges, add a new edge from `mid(AD)` to `mid(BC)`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by subdividing faces only... a face itself can not be subdivided without having the edges subdivided which build the face. Or do you mean without smoothing the shape? Like what the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier does when switching to _Simple_ option instead of _Catmull-Clark_?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann, maybe "only edges that belong to a face" makes more sense?

Comment: I can get you "better" with geometry nodes pretty simply, but using GN in this way means that you will no longer have valid vertex groups (for later use in a cloth modifier, perhaps.)  Do you need vertex groups for the follow up?

Comment: @Nathan, it's likely I'll need pinning groups, yes. Although I'd be interested to see a GN solution, because I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: You might consider adding GN tag and some info to being open to that (as well as requiring VGs) because there are others here that are more skilled with GN than I am, but might not deal with the q otherwise.  If you need VGs, I'm loathe to leave an answer that won't meet that criterion, but here's how I'd do it without worrying about them: https://imgur.com/a/ovO7szu